# Creating a news feed in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to create an activity feed from recent article and comments in my rails app. They are two different types of activerecord (their table structures are different).

Ideally I would be able to create a mixed array of articles and comments and then show them in reverse chronological order.

So, I can figure out how to get an array of both articles and comments and then merge them together and sort by created_at, but I'm pretty sure that won't work as soon as I start using pagination as well.

Is there any way to create a scope like thing that will create a mixed array?

One of the other problems for me, is that it could be all articles and it could be all comments or some combination in between. So I can't just say I'll take the 15 last articles and the 15 last comments.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: this might help you out http://mickeyben.com/2010/05/23/creating-an-activity-feed-with-rails,-ar-and-observers.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I've [done this before](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/members/madlep) I've managed it by having a denormalised `UserActivity` model or similar with a `belongs_to` polymorphic association to an `ActivitySource` - which can be any of the types of content that you want to display (posts, comments, up votes, likes, whatever...).

Then when any of the entities to be displayed are created, you have an `Observer` that fires and creates a row in the `UserActivity` table with a link to the record.

Then to display the list, you just query on `UserActivity` ordering by `created_at` descending, and then navigate through the polymorphic `activity_source` association to get the content data. You'll then need some smarts in your view templates to render comments and posts and whatever else differently though.

E.g. something like...

user_activity.rb:

```
class UserActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity_source, :polymorphic => true

  # awesomeness continues here...
end
```

comment.rb (post/whatever)

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # comment awesomeness here...
end
```

activity_source_observer.rb

```
class ActivitySourceObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  observe :comment, :post

  def after_create(activity_source)
    UserActivity.create!(
      :user => activity_source.user, 
      :activity_source_id => activity_source.id, 
      :activity_source_type => activity_source.class.to_s, 
      :created_at => activity_source.created_at, 
      :updated_at => activity_source.updated_at)
  end

  def before_destroy(activity_source)
    UserActivity.destroy_all(:activity_source_id => activity_source.id)
  end

end
```

Comment: One problem with this is that when a model is destroyed, you're destroying its associated activities rather than creating an activity for the destruction.  Imagine an activity feed like github's; when you create a repository, that gets posted to your feed.  When you delete a repository your feed shows that you deleted a repository.

Comment: @bratsche i feel like that is an edge case.  this is an inherently messy/complicated thing to build, for my purposes, if someone deletes a record, I actually DO want the feed items removed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) railscast.

Then you can paginate 15 articles and in `app/views/articles/index` you can do something like this:

```
 - @articles.each do |article|
   %tr
     %td= article.body
   %tr
     %td= nested_comments article.comment.descendants.arrange(:order => :created_at, :limit => 15)
```

This assumes the following relations:

```
 #app/models/article.rb
 has_one :comment # dummy root comment

 #app/models/comment.rb
 belongs_to :article
 has_ancestry
```

And you add comments to an article as follows:

```
 root_comment = @article.build_comment
 root_comment.save
 new_comment = root_comment.children.new
 # add reply to new_comment
 new_reply = new_comment.children.new
```

And so forth.